# preg_replace matching a string between chars but exclude some chars PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I still struggle with preg_match patterns.  I have the following set of strings stored in an array.

```
$comics = array("ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 (MR) $3.99","ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 FINAL JUSTICE CVR (MR) $3.99","ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 HAPPY KITTY PREMIUM CVR (MR) $9.99", "ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 WRAP CVR (MR) $3.99","SONIC THE HEDGEHOG #253 REG CVR $2.99");

ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 (MR) $3.99 
ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 FINAL JUSTICE CVR (MR) $3.99 
ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 HAPPY KITTY PREMIUM CVR (MR) $9.99 
ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 WRAP CVR (MR) $3.99
SONIC THE HEDGEHOG #253 REG CVR $2.99
```

I want to do a preg_match so that the final list looks like this

```
ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 (MR) $3.99 
SONIC THE HEDGEHOG #253 REG CVR $2.99

cleanComics = array("ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 (MR) $3.99","SONIC THE HEDGEHOG #253 REG CVR $2.99");
```

To give it context, these are comic titles and I want to eliminate the variant covers but every once in awhile a publisher will slip in a REG CVR and I need to keep this one.

These patterns remain constant.

- Comic Titles are always in all caps and are at the start of the string but they will contain a mix of letters and numbers.
- Issue numbers follow the Comic Title and starts with '#' symbol COMIC TITLE #000
- The Last set of characters will be the price and it will always use a '$' as the start of the price.
- Items appearing in '()' are not always present (these can be deleted they are not essential if it makes things easier)
- The names of the variant covers will vary and can contain a mix of numbers and letters but the letters CVR always follow the name of the variant cover.

I'm thinking that the last digit of the issue number and the $ sign could be the delimiters, I'm just not sure how to structure the match pattern to do this and exclude the REG CVR cases.

Should have mentioned this is done in PHP.

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: what reg exp have you already tried?

Comment: @A.O. Nothing yet, I'm a novice at reg expressions and have trouble even getting started.

Comment: well if you want someone to do the work for you, maybe you should explain more clearly what you want. i simply cant work out what you want to keep and discard

Comment: I'm prepearing something for you... I have to fix something silly in the regular expression and will be finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like a charm :D

```
    <?
$comics = array("ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 (MR) $3.99",
                "ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 FINAL JUSTICE CVR (MR) $3.99",
                "ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 HAPPY KITTY PREMIUM CVR (MR) $9.99", 
                "ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 WRAP CVR (MR) $3.99",
                "SONIC THE HEDGEHOG #253 REG CVR $2.99");

$added = Array();
$output = Array();
foreach ($comics as $title){
    $temp = preg_replace("/ #([0-9])* ([\\\(]|[\\\)]|[a-z]|[ ]|[A-Z])* \\\$*([0-9])*.([0-9])*/", "", $title);
    if (!in_array($temp, $added)){
        $added[count($added)] = $temp;
        $output[count($output)] = $title;
    }
}
foreach ($output as $data){
    echo "$data<br>";
}
?>
```

Just a comment:

If you have:

```
 $comics = array("ABSOLUTION RUBICON #4 (MR) $3.99",
            "ABSOLUTION RUBICON #5 FINAL JUSTICE CVR (MR) $3.99",
            "ABSOLUTION RUBICON #6 HAPPY KITTY PREMIUM CVR (MR) $9.99", 
            "ABSOLUTION RUBICON #7 WRAP CVR (MR) $3.99",
            "SONIC THE HEDGEHOG #253 REG CVR $2.99");
```

The output will still have only 2 results. If you want 5 results for this case you will need to change the regex to this one:

```
$temp = preg_replace("/([\\\(]|[\\\)]|[a-z]|[ ]|[A-Z])* \\\$*([0-9])*.([0-9])*/", "", $title);
```

Comment: looks like a good starting point, I should have mentioned I need to keep the issue number and the price, sorry.  Let me play around with it

Comment: Yes, works perfect thank you.  I really need to learn more regular expressions, my projects always grind to halt when I run into one.

Comment: I learnt how to use them the last week because I needed a complicated one... is not THAT difficult when you get how they work.

Comment: Thanks, I see that, fortunately the list is exclusive to what is shipping that week so there shouldn't be a mix of issue numbers but I will make note of it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use preg_replace:

```
$result = preg_replace('~#[0-9]++ \K.*?CVR~', '', $comics);
```

Comment: He will get 4 ABSOLUTION RUBICON